# append div after img tag dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, animation

I want to include a div with classname "new-fish" dynamically after the image tag within the section div when I click on post button. the new div included should have new id along with it. Based on the number of clicks so many divs should get added.
When i tried with the below code it didnt get appended.

```
  <section class="main-content" id="container">
  <div class="oyster"> </div>
  <div class="small-fish" id="fish1"> </div>
  <div class="medium-fish" id="fish2"> </div>
  <div class="large-fish" id="fish3"> </div>

  <img src="Assets/Arrow.png" class="right-arrow" alt="arrow" id="rightarrow" /> 

  </section>

 <footer> <input type="button" value="Post" class="post-button" /></footer>

/*Jquery */
$('.post-button').on('click',function(e){

    //$('#container img:last-child').append('<div class="small-fish"> </div>');
    $('#rightarrow').append('<div class="new-fish"> </div>');



});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should put your code inside

```
$(document).ready(function() { ... })
```

so that it will be called after dom is loaded and the button with class `post-button` will exist for sure.

The id `rightarrow` references an image and you can't put a div inside an image: what you want to do is append the div to section with id `main-content`, and it will be added to end of the section right after the image. Of course, when you add another div, it will be put after the previous one added.

As for the id, you could keep a variable to count the numbers of click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var numberOfClicks = 0;

    $('.post-button').on('click',function(e){
        numberOfClicks++;
        $('#container').append('<div id="appendedDiv'+numberOfClicks+'" class="new-fish"> </div>');

    }); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot append an element an image, you might be looking for is to insert the `new-fish` as the next sibling of the image then use [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```
$('#rightarrow').after('<div class="new-fish"> </div>');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mD34n/), [Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mD34n/2/)

Comment: how can make sure each div has a new id ??

Comment: @user3218194 see the second demo

Answer (score 0):

use like this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var i=0;
$('.post-button').on('click',function(e){
$('#container').append("<div class='new-fish' id='new-fish"+i+"'>coming </div>");
i++;
}); 

});
```